# Odoo - property fields bugged? Messes account moves

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

It seems there is some strange bug, which is hard to reproduce, but when it happens I don't see a way how to work around it..

I noticed this with property fields in product for valuation, like `property_stock_journal`, `property_stock_account_output_categ' and so on.

The problem is this. Some of the company property fields are not recognized. What I mean in view, for example I select specific account when I am representing that company. I save changes, I see that I assigned those accounts, but when I do transfer I get error like this:

`One of the following information is missing on the product or product category and prevents the accounting valuation entries to be created:
Product: Fresh new Product
Stock Input Account: False
Stock Output Account: False
Stock Valuation Account: False
Stock Journal: 1`

The weird part is that I selected those accounts, but Odoo still sees it like there is no such fields defined. And for one company even weirder thing happened, it somehow uses other company property field values, instead of the one user is representing. And If I switch back to that company, change values of those fields, then switch again, In warning I will see values that were defined in that other company. 
**But values that were set in company user is representing, won't have any effect**. Also some of the companies work normally, some are bugged like I described.

I also checked these fields using `shell` module in interactive python. This way it returns correct values. And going into `ir_property` table, I can see correct values set for all companies. But still for some reason when doing Transfer of goods (from Supplier to WH), it just does not see those values or sees another company values instead.

**Note about reproducing**. I don't know how to specifically reproduce it, but now it happened to me on two different databases. This bug is quite dangerous, because it might mess things without user even noticing it.

Can anyone suggest how can I debug property fields in depth or maybe know what could be wrong? Cause I ran out of ideas where to look.